# don't know how to detect variables using batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I am working on a game using batch where you will be given different options, each time an option is given I need the variable to go up by one, however since some options just take you in a circle I need it to be flexible. I also need to know how to tell if the variable is equal to 4 or something along those lines, how would I accomplish this?

EDIT: Once this question is no longer on hold I will post the solution I have found.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect a variable?" Are you trying to determine if a variable is defined?

Comment: by detect a variable I mean detect what the variable is and how to make that run commands E.G. detect if the variable is 2, run command exit

Comment: Ohhh, you want to just get the value of the variable! Variables are referenced like this: `%variable%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set` to change the value of variables and `%var%` for using them:

```
set variable=4
echo Variable is equal to %variable%.
pause
```

Output:

> Variable is equal to 4.
>   Press a key to continue . . .

If you mean you want to know if a variable is defined, just use `if defined <variable>`:

```
if defined myVar (echo Defined!) else (echo myVar isn't defined.)
```

It will output *Defined!* if myVar is defined, *myVar isn't defined* else.

Comment: Did you run it? Remove spaces around the `=` equals sign, use `set "variable=4"`.

Comment: @Josef I thought it worked too. Thanks, I already edited it :)